# Returning multiple search queries with a single search bar?

Tags: php

I am attempting to search using a form action. Basically what I'd like is 10 search fields for ticket ID's that would then return each ticket id in the search bar.

**FORM:**

```
<form action="http://-withheld-/adminhelper/-withheld-/ticket.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="id1" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="id2" placeholder="Search by TicketID" required="required">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $url = 'http://-withheld-.com/api/v1/tickets/'.$id.'?api_key=withheld';

        //  Initiate curl
        $ch = curl_init();
        // Disable SSL verification
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        // Will return the response, if false it print the response
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        // Set the url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        // Execute
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        // Closing
        curl_close($ch);

        // Will dump a beauty json :3
        $jsonObj = json_decode($result);
        ?>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Ticket ID</th>
                <th>Ticket Number</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Issue Type</th>
                <th>Updated</th>
                <th>Detail</th>
            </tr>
        <?php

        $ticket = $jsonObj->{'ticket'};

        $link_addr = 'http://-withheld-/adminhelper/-withheld-/singleticket.php?id='.$ticket->{'id'};

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'id'}.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'number'}.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'customer_business_then_name'}.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'subject'}.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'created_at'}.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'status'}.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'problem_type'}.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ticket->{'updated_at'}.'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.$link_addr.'">Detail</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

As you can see, I am using the GET method to retrieve the data and I've tried to create a second search field while utilizing a single submit "search" button return multiple values but whenever I search it only seems to use one of the fields. Does anyone have any experience with this? The reason I want to do this is so that our data entry clerk can search for multiple tickets and review them in a list without having to go to each ticket 1 by 1.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Oh and yes, I am using an API key here, not connecting directly to a SQL database.

Comment: Youre sending `id1` and `id2` but asking for `id` only!?

Comment: @Jeff, My apologies. I pasted a bit of a dated version of my php code. I had the id names specified but for some reason when I search im getting a blank page.

Comment: Any Errors? Error-reporting is switched on? var_dumped $result?

Comment: Does your API allow you to search more than one ID at a time? If so, just use `$_GET["id1"]` and `$_GET["id2"]`.

Comment: Looks like I can't query for more than one ID at a time. Darn API!